# Travel to Korea with I-327 Travel Document

Tags: paperwork, south-korea, us-permanent-residents

I am wondering if South Korea accepts I-327 Travel Document (US Re-entry Permit) in lieu of a passport either for visa free travel or for visa issuance purposes. Anyone has the experience?

Comment: References here https://www.visa.go.kr/openPage.do?MENU_ID=10105 under ‘required documents’ all seem to state *passport*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TIMATIC states :

> Korea (Rep. of), South - Destination Passport
>
> Passport required.
>
> Passport Exemptions
>
> Passengers with a travel document issued to refugees or stateless persons.
>
> Document Validity
>
> Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid on
> arrival.

Contrary to some countries (like most [EU Members](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/prado-recognised-documents.html)) South Korea doesn't recognize a I-327 with the mention *Permit to re-enter* as a passport replacement

For visa requirements, US PRs used to have [(now paused)](https://www.visa.go.kr/openPage.do?MENU_ID=1010201#visa_list08_en) a transit visa exemption (going to/from the US only) for 30 days

Comment: So stateless people and refugees cannot visit South Korea?

Comment: @phoog A I-327 is not a I-571 despite using the same booklet, this is for the Re-entry permit variant

Comment: I know that, but this answer says that it's impossible to visit South Korea without a passport.

Comment: @phoog I hold neither a professional TIMATIC access nor an ExpertFlyer subscription and this is the habitual shortcoming of the freely available copies of TIMATIC, it doesn't state all exemptions on every query (it states exemptions if relevant for that particular query). Added the relevant exemption manually

Comment: The US doesn't have a "travel document for stateless persons". It does have a Refugee Travel Document, but that only covers people who are asylees or refugees, or who got their green card from asylee or refugee status. Stateless green card holders who were never asylees or refugees can only use the Re-entry Permit. So does that mean that a stateless green card holder who was never an asylee or refugee cannot travel to South Korea?

Comment: @user102008 This seems to be the case indeed

Comment: Hey, so I tried https://www.united.com/en/us/timatic?i=TIMATIC&POS=US&POS=US and in the exemptions it actually says "Passengers with an Alien's passport". Why would it be different?

Comment: @sencer: The US doesn't have an "alien's passport". Only Lithuania, Latvia, and Estonia have "alien's passports".